# Add number of second level groups in esttab after mixed

Tags: stata, multi-level

I am running multilevel random intercept models with the `mixed` command in Stata `14` SE.

I want to export the results with the *community-contributed* command `esttab` but I cannot figure out how to add the number of second level groups to the output, which in my case it's rather important.

More specifically, I cannot seem to find the number of groups if I run `ereturn list`, even though Stata displays it after the `mixed` command.

Here is an example of the code:

```
mixed defect c.cenretrosoc c.centrust i.wave || countrywave:
est sto H1A_

mixed defect c.centrust i.wave##c.cenretrosoc || countrywave:
est sto H1A_2

mixed defect c.cenretrosoc i.wave##c.centrust || countrywave:
est sto H1A_3

mixed defect i.wave##c.centrust##c.cenretrosoc || countrywave:
est sto H1A_4

esttab H1A_1 H1A_2 H1A_3 H1A_4 using "defect_all.rtf", b(a1) nobaselevels nocons aic bic ///
scalars("ll Log lik." "nrgroups") label title(Defection - EU members) interact(*) ///
nonumbers mtitles("Baseline" "Econ*Wave" "Misrep*Wave" "Econ*Misrep*Wave") ///
starlevels(~ 0.10 * 0.05 ** 0.01 *** 0.001) nonote replace
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `estadd` to add the number of second level groups from returned matrix `N_g` as a 
scalar in `e()`:

```
webuse nlswork, clear
estimates clear

mixed ln_w age c.age#c.age tenure c.tenure#c.tenure || id:
estimates store H1A_1
matrix A = e(N_g)
estadd scalar ngrps = A[1,1]

mixed ln_w grade age tenure c.tenure#c.tenure || id:
estimates store H1A_2
matrix A = e(N_g)
estadd scalar ngrps = A[1,1]

mixed ln_w grade age c.age#c.age ttl_exp || id:
estimates store H1A_3
matrix A = e(N_g)
estadd scalar ngrps = A[1,1]

mixed ln_w grade age ttl_exp tenure || id:
estimates store H1A_4
matrix A = e(N_g)
estadd scalar ngrps = A[1,1]
```

Then simply feed this to `esttab` with the rest of the required scalars:

```
esttab H1A_1 H1A_2 H1A_3 H1A_4, b(a1) nobaselevels nocons aic bic ///
scalars("ll Log lik." "ngrps") label title(My custom title) interact(*) ///
nonumbers mtitles("First" "Second" "Third" "Fourth") ///
starlevels(~ 0.10 * 0.05 ** 0.01 *** 0.001) nonote

My custom title
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            First          Second           Third          Fourth   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ln(wage/GNP deflat~)                                                                
age in current year          0.05***        0.010***         0.04***       -0.004***
                          (16.63)         (26.17)         (16.56)         (-6.78)   

age in current yea~e      -0.0006***                      -0.0009***                
                         (-12.69)                        (-19.58)                   

job tenure, in years         0.05***         0.05***                         0.01***
                          (29.95)         (32.73)                         (15.96)   

job tenure, in yea~,       -0.002***       -0.002***                                
                         (-15.32)        (-18.32)                                   

current grade comp~d                         0.08***         0.07***         0.07***
                                          (42.11)         (39.29)         (41.23)   

total work experie~e                                         0.04***         0.03***
                                                          (43.82)         (26.92)   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                28101           28099           28508           28099   
AIC                       20726.5         19381.0         19263.8         19002.3   
BIC                       20784.2         19438.7         19321.6         19060.0   
Log lik.                 -10356.3         -9683.5         -9624.9         -9494.2   
ngrps                        4699            4697            4708            4697   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```