# Number of groups in esttab (after xtmixed)

Tags: stata

i'd like to add the number of groups to a `esttab` output after fitting a multilevel model in Stata (`xtmixed`). I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138121/stata-14-number-of-groups-after-mixed-in-esttab) and understand that the number of groups is stores in the matrix e(N_g). However, I do not understand, how to use the value in this matrix and add it to the output. I tried `estadd` but did not manage to get it work. I also did not find something about using a single cell of a matrix in an output in the estout manual.

Any ideas on how to add the number of gorups to a esttab output? Or maybe experiences with adding single values from a matrix?

Thx!!!

P.S. This is the output of `matrix list e(N_g)`

```
symmetric e(N_g)[1,1]
    c1
r1  117
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estadd is the way to go, here is an example:

```
clear all
webuse pig

// model
eststo: xtmixed weight week || id:, vce(robust)

// estadd portion - pull the single element of the matrix into a local and estadd it
matrix N_g = e(N_g)
local groups = N_g[1,1]
estadd local groups `groups'

// add groups in the stats option and it will appear at the bottom along
// with the number of observations in this case
esttab ., stats(N groups)
```

Comment: Just a short addition: If you want to define the display format of groups using ``esttab ., stats(N groups, fmt(2))`` it is better to use ``estadd scalar groups `groups'`` (s. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288364/problem-setting-number-formatting-in-table-output-after-using-estadd-esttab) ).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `esttab, stats(N_g, labels("N"))` is sufficient. `estout` can recognize `N_g`.